# vite(vue)+typescript error TS2304: Cannot find name 'title'

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vite

I am using vite(vue)+typescript for my project.

but when I run yarn build (vue-tsc --noEmit && vite build)

showing a bunch of this kind of error.

error TS2304: Cannot find name 'title'. [image]

but I'm pretty sure I did defined those variable.

[image]

I guess this is because the *setup* in `<script setup lang="ts">`?

here is my tsconfig.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom"
    ],
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    },
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.d.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue"
  ],
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.node.json"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 6):

simply upgrade vue-tsc version with `npm i vue-tsc -D`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Also try typescript version ^4.7.4

Answer (score 2):

I got the same issue with typescript version 4.8.2 and old vue-tsc version 0.2.3, fixed it with typescript 4.8.2 and vue-tsc 0.40.5 (the latest version)

Answer (score 0):

Try updating package.json to the following settings. In particular, change the "build" script to "vite build". That usually addresses this problem.

```
 "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "serve": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^3.2.45"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^2.3.4",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
    "vite": "^2.9.15",
    "vue-tsc": "^0.31.4"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run just this command:

```
yarn add @volar/typescript-faster
```